# Отмена всех Task'ов если один поймал исключение

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, асинхронность

Добрый вечер!

У меня возник такой вопрос. Есть класс наследник `AsyncTask`. Этот класс выполняет загрузку файла по `url`. Я запускаю несколько таких тасков, и они работают.

Предположим, вдруг оборвалось соединение с интернетом и один из этих тасков поймал соответствующее исключение. Вполне логично, что если соединения с сетью нет, то нужно отменить все таски и показать сообщение об ошибке.

Я делаю это так: каждый таск содержит в себе массив тасков, запущенных вместе с ним. Если отлавливается исключение то выполняется код вроде этого:

```
try {
    // bla-bla-bla
} catch(Exception ex) {
    if(_tasks != null) {
        for(MyTask task : _tasks) {
            if(task != null && !task.isCancelled()) {
                 task.cancel(true);
                 task = null;
            }    
        }
        showErrorMessage(ex);
    } 
}
```

Правильно ли я делаю?

Дело в том, что я не очень силен в работе с многопоточным кодом, а тут как раз задействовано несколько потоков как я понимаю. Может быть тут необходима какая-то синхронизация, неправильно отменяются таски  или еще что?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вы считаете что несколько ```AsyncTask``` по умолчанию работают параллельно, то вы ошибаетесь - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . Так же google рекомендует использовать ```AsyncTask``` для коротких задач. Очевидно что загрузка по сети это не этот случай. Поэтому лучше для загрузки использовать что-то другое, например ```Service``` или стороннюю библиотеку, например ```RoboSpice```, хотя она так же построена на использовании сервисов. И уже там загружать все это вместе. Тогда отпадет необходимость отменять целую кучу тасков и т.д.